# Changing Wordpress background colour smoothly on page scroll

Tags: wordpress

Can't seem to find an answer via search so wonder if anybody has advice please?

How to achieve a background effect like this - http://ustwo.com/

...easily :-)

Is there a plugin that might do it, for example?

Thank you.

Comment: Inspeciting the javascript would have learned you this is done via a javascript called "Scrollmagic" http://scrollmagic.io/. Implementing a custom javascript in Wordpress is a piece of cake if you are writing your own theme.

Comment: OK... that's a useful bit of information, thank you. I am not writing my own theme but, rather, am hoping to integrate it into an existing theme.